# Is there a good reason infant baptism shouldn't have its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions on infant baptism currently need to be tagged with two tags: [infants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infants) and [baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism). This goes against the general principle that distinct topics should have their own tags, and not be inferred from the combination of tags.

1. Is there any good reason why there shouldn't be a [infant-baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant-baptism) tag?
2. Should it be [infant-baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant-baptism) or [paedobaptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paedobaptism)? The first is simpler IMO, but the second could be a synonym.
3. Should questions keep the [baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism) or [infants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infants) tags if they get the new tag?

Comment: Searching for "infants" + "baptism" would find inappropriate questions like "Why do [denomination] forbid infants attending adult baptism ceremonies?".  So I'd say that a single "infant-baptism" (or "baptism-infants" or whatever) tag would be appropriate.  I suspect that such a change might even make the "infant" tag no longer needed.  I also suspect than many people won't know to use the word "paedobaptism".

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no reason not to.

The correct theological term is [paedobaptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paedobaptism), the colloquial [infant-baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant-baptism) should be a synonym to it.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not so sure about this now. The [tag:infants] tag makes no sense and I'm still far [tag:paedobaptism], but dropping [tag:baptism] seems wrong.

Comment: If you exclude the infant baptism question there are still a fair number of questions on the moral capacity, sinfulness, and afterlife of infants, so I think the tag makes sense. But perhaps it could be merged with [tag:children].

Comment: I would usually keep [tag:baptism] on these if there's room, as a high-level tag.  Like how we might have both [tag:soteriology] and [tag:penal-substitution] on the same question.

Answer (score -2):

[paedobaptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paedobaptism) is probably only something someone who is looking for arguments against the practice is going to use, that's not term you're going to find sects that baptize infants using unless it's got the phrase "so called" in front of it.

I think calling it something other than [baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism) really takes away from its eternal significance; Catholics believe it leaves an indelible mark on your soul regardless of the age the Sacrament was administered.

I'd prefer [baptism-of-infants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism-of-infants) as the main tag, then [infant-baptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant-baptism) and [paedobapatism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paedobapatism) for the pendants among us.

Comment: There's a lot of work to do with retags if you're gonna [go through with this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22infant+baptism%22) Looks like 35 questions contain the phrase "Infant Baptism", 3 contain "Baptism of Infants".

Comment: Protestants who baptise infants absolutely do use both infant baptism and paedobaptism to refer to their own doctrines.